# When migrating from Angular 1.5 to 1.6 routing is ran inside unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've migrated my app to Angular 1.6 and suddenly unit test aren't working anymore. After investigating a little I found out that routing is enabled when running unit tests.

The code that I have added extra to the $routeProvider is this one:

```js
$routeProvider.whenAuthenticated = function (path, route) {
    route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
    
    angular.extend(route.resolve, {
        isAuthenticated: ['Auth', function (auth) {
             return auth.authenticate();
        }]
    });

    return $routeProvider.when(path, route);
};
```

and

```
$routeProvider
    .whenAuthenticated('/', {
        redirectTo: '/dashboards'
    });
```

In Angular 1.5 the `auth.authenticate()` is never hit, while in Angular 1.6 the app tries to navigate to one of my routes and then `auth.authenticate()` is hit, and the url changes to "/dashboards".
Does anybody have an idea about what changed in 1.6? Do I need to do something extra to disable routing while testing?

Comment: ngRoute module shouldn't be included in unit tests at all. $route and $routeProvider should be mocked.

Comment: shouldn't angular mock these by itself? the angular-mocks module is loaded...

Comment: No, it shouldn't. You may check ngMock source code to make sure which services it mocks. But you can be sure that it affects only core services.

Comment: Then why did it work until now? I have the tests written this way since Angular 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.6 the way the $route service and its dependencies are instantiated has changed, and will - by default - be instantiated early on.

[Migrating from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ngRoute)